# ASP.NET MVC 4.0 model binder not working with collection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

The default model binder is not mapping the collections in my model. Here is my code:

Model:

```
public class Company
{
   public string Name;
   public List<CompanyActivity> Activities
}

public class CompanyActivity
{
   public string  Code;
   public string Description
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Company company) {}
```

View/HTML:

```
<input name="Name" type="text" value="some name" />
<input name="Activities[0].Code" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="Activities[0].Description" type="text" value="a" />
<input name="Activities[1].Code" type="text" value="2" />
<input name="Activities[1].Description" type="text" value="b" />
```

The Name input is mapped but the Activities list is empty.

Comment: The HTML you've given shows the `value=""` attribute as empty. What happens when you provide values? Also, what is your MVC view source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your model with fields, but you have to use properties. You only have to change your model for this:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyActivity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyActivity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Differences between fields and properties: [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0) and [ASP.net MVC - Model binding excludes class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789674/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-excludes-class-fields)

Comment: why? I have created a proyect with your code. Without properties dont bind and with properties bind properly. The HTML is right, like I said I have only added the {get;set;} and it works fine.

Comment: Interesting I didn't realize the modelbinder was smart enough to do this using that name syntax. My answer is not nearly as neat in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The names need to be identical for it to build them as a collection/array:

I would create a ViewModel to handle this case, this is why I almost always build a ViewModel to handle view rendering and the idiosyncrasies of MVC.

**Model**

```
public class Company
{
   public string Name;
   public List<CompanyActivity> Activities
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
   public string Name;

   //View specific
   public List<int> CompanyActivityCodes
}
```

**View**

```
<input name="Name" type="text" value="" />
<input name="CompanyActivityCodes" type="text" value="" />
<input name="CompanyActivityCodes" type="text" value="" />
```

This will then bind the CompanyActivityCodes property, you can then reassign these to build up the Activities property in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(CompanyViewModel companyViewModel) 
{
  var company = new Company { Name = companyViewModel }; 
  company.Activities = companyViewModel.CompanyActivityCodes.Select(x =>  new CompanyActivity { Code = x });
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Activities is a list of objects, not a list of ints.

Comment: yes but it's not that clever where it can figure out the nested properties when using collections.

Comment: I understand, the modelbinder is not advanced enough however to figure out the nested properties when working with collections. 
For this reason I created a ViewModel which essentially "flattens" you CompanyActivity class into a flat class.

As you see I have named the property CompanyActivityCodes as it flattens the code property in the activities collection.

You've edited the question to include additional properties which complicates matters.

Answer (score 0):

it shoould be

```
<input name="company.Activities[0].Code" type="text" value="" />
```