# Asp.Net MVC 4 Automatically bind model from array of objects in form post

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, form-post

I have built an array of objects in JavaScript and want to post them back to the server via Ajax (Im using jQuery)

The JavaScript object array looks like this:

```
var columns = [
    { name: 'col 1', source: 'whatever', hidden: false, width: 50 },
    ...
];
```

Im posting it back like this:

```
$.post('/MyController/MyAction', { 'columns': columns });
```

On the controller action Im currently getting this:

[image]

I have a c# object called `JqColumn` that I want to bind the post into, it looks like this:

```
public class JqGridColumn
{
    public string name;
    public string source;
    public int width;
    public bool hidden;
}
```

So I thought that adding a parameter in the controller action of type `JqGridColumn[] columns` would automatically bind the posted data, but it doesn't (it generates a array, with the correct number of elements, but each item in the array has blank values)

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

At present, I am manually binding the items in my controller action as follows:

```
    public void ColumnChooser(JqGridColumn[] columns)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
        {
            columns[i].hidden = bool.Parse(Request.Form["columns[" + i + "][hidden]"]);
            columns[i].width = int.Parse(Request.Form["columns[" + i + "][width]"]);
            columns[i].name = Request.Form["columns[" + i + "][name]"];
            columns[i].source = Request.Form["columns[" + i + "][source]"];
        }
        return;
    }
```

...which works fine, but I'd really like to know the .Net MVC (correct) way to do it!

Comment: Have you tried making the fields on your JqGridColumn object into properties (ie, add a get & set) as it sounds the the model binder can't find the fields

Comment: Tried and still no joy I'm afraid... :(

Comment: Have you tried using a WebApi Controller, the model binding might be handled differently using the WebAPI Controller as the default MVC binding (i think) depends on HTML Elements being posted back in a FormCollection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you didn't register a specific `ModelBinder` for the `JqGridColumn` type, the `DefaultModelBinder` will be used. But:

- It won't bind Fields, only public Properties.
- The expected format for Array binding is `columns[0].name` while you're actually posting `columns[0][name]`.

The problem could be solved easily if you'll simply send your `columns` in **JSON** format instead of **Name-Value-Pairs**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/MyAction',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ columns: columns })
});
```

Yet, if you don't like to change your class, you could register a `ModelBinder` specific for `JqGridColumn` and have it working even with Fields and current jQuery serialization:

```
public class JqGridColumnBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        string name = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "[name]").AttemptedValue;
        string source = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "[source]").AttemptedValue;
        int width = (int)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "[width]").ConvertTo(typeof(int));
        bool hidden = (bool)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "[hidden]").ConvertTo(typeof(bool));

        return new JqGridColumn
        {
            name = name,
            source = source,
            width = width,
            hidden = hidden
        };
    }
}
```

Then register it in **App_Start/ModelBindingConfig.cs**:

```
binders.Add(typeof(JqGridColumn), new JqGridColumnBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks :) Didn't want to use a custom model binder, so the JSON.stringify for the win!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your JqGridColumn object needs properties, not fields. see this question for reference:

[ASP.net MVC - Model binding excludes class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789674/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-excludes-class-fields)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately, even when the JqGridColumn variables are changed to properties, they still don't get bound.

Comment: You could try changing it to a `List<JqGridColumn>` instead of an array. I don't think it'll help as your getting the right number of items.

Comment: On the off chance that it might work, I tried changing to a List<JqGridColumn> but still no binding :(

Answer (score 0):

try post back with the traditional : true setting
and dataType: json

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/MyAction',
    method: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    dataType: json
    data: columns ,            
    sucess: function () { alert('Success'); }
});
```

Comment: Even with this change, the form post is still seen the same by the controller.