# Model is null in controller even after fixing get set in model definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had an application that was weakly typed and I decided that it would be best to change it to strongly typed... however I am running into some issues.

My controller delivers a new model to my razor view (which has a small form in it). I use textboxfor(model => mymodel.type) and post it back to my controller. I can see that the post has the needed values but once it hits my controller the model is null.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogIn(int Op)
        {
                    LoginWrapperClass newOperation = new LoginWrapperClass();
                    newOperation.newL = new ePSDB();
                    newOperation.newP = new eP(Op, Request.Cookies["State"].Value);
                    return View(newOperation);
            }

  [HttpPost, ValidateInput(true)]
        public ActionResult LogIn(LoginWrapperClass newOperation)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                newOperation.LookUp();
                if (newOperation.newP != null)
                {
                    //stuff

                    return RedirectToAction("RecordOp", "Authenticated", newOperation.newP);
                }
            }
```

View:

```
@model WebApp.Models.LoginWrapperClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Operation";
}

<div id="indexOp" class="textCenter">
    <div id="time"></div>
    <div id="loader" class="hiddenAndGone"><img src="~/Content/Images/loader.gif"></div>
    <div id="operations">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            //Html.AntiForgeryToken();
            <div class="Ops">
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newL.BADGE_NBR, new { @id = "BADGE_NBR", @class = "readFont", autofocus = "autofocus", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newP.PUNCH_TYPE, new { type="number", @class = "hidden" })
                </div>
                <div id="submit" class="hidden">
                    <input type="submit" value="validate" class="validateSubmit"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, through fiddler, I can see the post contains the values I need but the controller's model is null. Why?

What I am posting is this:
`newL.BADGE_NBR=18845733&newP.PUNCH_TYPE=1`

---

I am adding class declarations here:

```
 public class LoginWrapperClass
    {
        public ePSDB newL { get; set; } //fixed per Aaron's response... still no binding
        public eP newP{ get; set; }
        public void LookUp()
        {
            using (var db = new PSTestEntities())
            {
                IEnumerable<ePSDB> foundInDb;
                foundInDb = db.ePSDBs.Where(foundE => this.newL.BADGE_NBR.ToString() == foundE.BADGE_NBR.ToString().Substring(3));

                if (foundInDb.Count() > 0)
                {

                    this.newL = foundInDb.First();
                    this.newP.BADGE_NBR = this.newL.BADGE_NBR;
                    this.newP.EMPLID = this.newL.EMPLID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//This is a partial class that will be added to but as of now this is all
    public partial class ePSDB
        {
            [Key]
            public int P_Key { get; set; }
            public int EMPLID { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public long BADGE_NBR { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> BIRTHDATE { get; set; }
            public string NAME { get; set; }
        }

    public partial class eP
    {
        [Required]
        public long BADGE_NBR { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int EMPLID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public System.DateTimeOffset PUNCH_DTTM { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int PUNCH_TYPE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> TL_QUANTITY { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public long P_Key { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class eP
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public bool containsQuestions = false;
        [NotMapped]
        public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
        public eP(int punchType, string state)
        {
            PUNCH_DTTM = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            PUNCH_TYPE = punchType;
            if((punchType == 1 || punchType == 2) & containsQuestions)
                questions = getQuestions(state, punchType);
        }
    private List<Question> getQuestions(string state, int punchType){
        List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>();
      //do stuff
      return Questions
     }
        ///plus other methods not used in this controller/view
    }
public class Question
    {
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
        public string QuestionString { get; set; }
        public int Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do all the properties of your view model have public setters? If not model binding won't work

Comment: @ScottRickman, Yup they are all public, just double checked.

Comment: @user2072256 Model structure is an important part of model binding.  Need to show `LoginWrapperClass` declaration as well as the type declartion for `newL` and `newP`

Comment: I.e. declaration of `ePSDB` and `eP`

Comment: @AaronLS Okay added them.

Comment: This is just a guess but `model => Model.newL.BADGE_NBR` should probably be `model => model.newL.BADGE_NBR`

Comment: @Nathan, changed that out- nice catch. However still having the same issue.

Comment: I see that your `eP` and `ePSDB` classes are partial. What is the other part? Make sure you have a default constructor in all model classes (public, parameterless)

Comment: @Iravanchi, Done. Also is a parameterless constructor necessary? I have a constructor but it takes two variables.

Comment: Nevermind... that is what I needed, a constructor.

Comment: @user2072256 Yes, it is necessary. Because when ASP.NET is binding the model, it needs to instantiate the objects and doesn't know what to pass as the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suffering from this I believe: [ASP.net MVC - Model binding excludes class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789674/84206)

You have this declaration using **fields**:

```
public class LoginWrapperClass
{
    public ePSDB newL;
    public eP newP;
    //...
}
```

But you need to be using **properties**:

```
public class LoginWrapperClass
{
    public ePSDB newL {get;set;}
    public eP newP {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the help. However it looks like this is still not binding correctly even after the get and set. When my view posts back it is looking for a parameterless controller... If I force it to use my controller with the wrapperclass model (by using beginfrom parameters in view) it will post a `null` model. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2072256 Did you look at the request in the browser?  I think by default BeginForm generates a GET request, and you action is marked HttpPost.  BeginForm lets you specify the Method as Post.  A route debugger may help if that doesn't solve it: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/