# WebApi data annotation validation not occuring for complex type parameter properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to ASP.Net WebApi.  Apologies therefore if this has been asked before (I'm unsure of the correct terminology), but I can only find [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493800/how-can-i-tell-the-data-annotations-validator-to-also-validate-complex-child-pro) which is slightly different to my problem.

I need to create a `Post` controller that accepts a complex type (a `TestObject`), containing:

1. An `IEnumerable<Person>`, where `Person` has properties `Username` and `ExternalId`
2. Options on how the controller should handle the data (a `TestOptions` object)

I have defined the classes below with data annotations to assist with validation:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public IEnumerable<TestPerson> TestPerson;
    public TestOptions Options;

    public void TestOject()
    {
        this.TestPerson = new List<TestPerson>();
        this.Options = new TestOptions();
    }
}

public class TestPerson
{
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string ExternalId;

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Username;
}

public class TestOptions
{
    [Required]
    public bool Option1;

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Option2;
}
```

The controller accepts `TestObject` and performs validation before doing anything:

```
    [Route("test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] TestObject t)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Format("Found {0} people", t.TestPerson.Count().ToString()));
        }
    }
```

If I use Fiddler to send a sample JSON object the with correct structures, it works fine.  However, if I deliberately introduce errors (E.g. `Username` and `Option2` missing) like this...

```
{
   "TestPerson":[
      { "ExternalId":"123", "Username":"Bob" },
      { "ExternalId":"123" }
   ],
   "Options":{"Option1":false}
}
```

I still get

> Status 200
>
> 2 people found

Why is this happening please?  Can I use data annotation validation on complex types?

## Update

Debugging image with property values being set:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using fields you need to convert them to properties for this to work:

```
[Required, MaxLength(50)]
public string ExternalId { get; set; }

[Required, MaxLength(50)]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

Do this for all of your public fields.

Did you look at the object using the debugger and see if the fields were being set? They probably were, but see here for some detail on modelbinding:

[ASP.net MVC - Model binding excludes class fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7789986/885626)

Update:

I have tried and tested this and am sure it will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I added getters and setters but the validation is *still* not occurring.  I've attached an image of the debugger showing values being set.  Perhaps you can spot something missing?

Comment: Yes, you didnt set the fields in `TestObject` to properties!

Comment: Arrgh; face-palm moment...  Thank you - it's working.  Just out of interest, do you know why this validation doesn't work on fields, and only properties.  The other question states it's by design, but is there a reason for that?

Comment: I've no idea why. Looked into it a bit but just accepted that this is the way it is!

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using TestPerson View that validator won't execute.
Use

```
if(ModelState.IsValid && TryValidateModel(model.TestPerson, "TestPerson."))
{
   //Submodel will be validated here.
}
```

Comment: Hi this isn't an MVC project so I don't have any Views